# Add polygon as text before the polygon values

Tags: graphics

I have the following values of two polygons:

```
aa= {{{235.086, 434.547}, {123.376, 373.614}, {223.462, 
  360.927}}, {{293.659, 363.962}, {304.17, 526.888}, {251.5, 
  449.564}, {251.5, 363.282}}}
```

Now, I want to add the polygon in front of them. So they look like this:

```
aa = {Polygon[{{235.086, 434.547}, {123.376, 373.614}, {223.462, 
360.927}}], 
  Polygon[{{293.659, 363.962}, {304.17, 526.888}, {251.5, 
  449.564}, {251.5, 363.282}}]}
```

Please let me know, how can I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Polygon /@ aa
```

will produce the result you ask for.

I wrap the list of two polygons produced by mapping the head `Polygon` over your list so we can visualize the polygons.

```
Graphics[
  Polygon /@ 
    {{{235.086, 434.547}, {123.376, 373.614}, {223.462, 360.927}}, 
     {{293.659, 363.962}, {304.17, 526.888}, {251.5, 449.564}, {251.5, 363.282}}}]
```

[image: polys]